Why is cURL failing to reach my server only in Docker and CircleCI?
I have written a web server in C++ with C socket calls including getaddrinfo and/or liberal use of setsockopt.
I can run the raw executable on my machine and connect to my server. I can also connect to the server over the internet when hosted from a static IP.
I can connect to my server when running inside Docker (or Docker-Compose) with ports forwarded. I can connect to my server as a raw executable when running in the same CircleCI job.
However the combination of running the Docker container inside a CircleCI job does not succeed. cURL cannot reach the server despite logs showing that the server is running normally.
What might be going on here?
version: 2.1
# circleci local execute --config ./.circleci/config.yml test_make
jobs:
  test_docker:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2024.07
    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Reset
          command: sudo docker rmi -f server && sudo docker rm -f server-container
      - run:
          name: Build image
          command: sudo docker build -t server .
      - run:
          name: Run image 
          command: sudo docker run --init -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d --name server-container --network=host server
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Sleep
          command: sleep 1
      - run:
          name: Logs
          command: sudo docker compose logs server #-f 
          #background: true
      - run:
          name: Check server
          command: sudo curl --insecure https://localhost
      - run:
          name: Stop container
          command: sudo docker stop server-container
      - run:
          name: Remove container
          command: sudo docker rm -f server-container
          when: always
      - run:
          name: Remove image
          command: sudo docker rmi -f server
          when: always

  test_make:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2024.07
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y g++-12 make
      - run:
          name: Verify g++ version
          command: g++ --version
      - run:
          name: Build project
          command: make -j8
      - run:
          name: Run
          command: |
            ./target/codeymccodeface
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Sleep
          command: sleep 1
      - run:
          name: Check server
          command: curl --insecure https://localhost

workflows:
  run_tests:
    jobs:
      - test_docker
      - test_make


